# Old unanswered question - should it be migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

I have an [old, unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463696/anonymous-users-cant-use-contact-forms) that must have been from before Drupal Answers was a proper SE site - it no longer belongs on Stack Overflow. It's old enough that the site won't let me migrate it. Should I do anything about it? I personally no longer need an answer to it, but I feel like I should do something to put it where it might eventually be answered.

Comment: Has it already been asked and answered on Drupal Answers?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Unless I missed something, no.

Comment: You can always *"manually migrate"* it, then; nobody loses any rep if you delete the question and re-post it (adding the information in your comment on the redundant answer) on another site.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but I figured I shouldn't because I don't really *need* an answer anymore. However, I suppose I am curious enough to fire up a fresh Drupal instance for testing in the event that someone does answer it.

Comment: If it really *"no longer belongs on Stack Overflow"*, you should probably delete it; it's up to you whether it's worth your while re-posting it.

Comment: I ended up doing a "manual migration" and deleting the original. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated, even by moderators.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yes, I read about that. I asked this question anyway because I felt this might be an unusual case - since it predates the site I felt it should now be migrated to.

Answer (score 1):

To close this question:

I manually copied the question to Drupal Answers and deleted the original at Stack Overflow. This made sense because there was only one answer to the original question, with no upvotes, which didn't solve the problem. (In fact, [the new question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164082/anonymous-users-cant-use-personal-contact-forms) has already attracted effectively the same non-helpful answer! Along with some other ideas, fortunately.)